# Java Android Send a data to server application never use a onPostExecute()

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I have a problem with send a data to server, to connect with server I used a socket. To send a data to server I use a AsyncTask. And I have a problem with :

when a application send a data , my app don't see a finish this action, it never use `onPostExecute()`.

This is my code :

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port) {
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
//            if (pingHost(1000)) {
            socket = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
                        new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                byte[] theByteArray = message.getBytes();
                lengthMessage = (short) theByteArray.length;

                outputStream.writeByte((byte) 0xB);
                outputStream.writeByte((byte) 0xA);
                outputStream.writeByte((byte) 0xA);
                outputStream.writeByte((byte) 0xD);
                outputStream.writeShort(lengthMessage);
                outputStream.write(theByteArray);
                outputStream.writeShort(width);
                outputStream.writeShort(height);
                outputStream.writeInt(lengthbmp);
                outputStream.writeInt(lengthResizebmp);
                outputStream.writeShort(11);
                outputStream.write(imageInByte );
                outputStream.write(imageResizeInByte);
                outputStream.writeByte((byte) 0xB);
                outputStream.writeByte((byte) 0xE);
                outputStream.writeByte((byte) 0xE);
                outputStream.writeByte((byte) 0xF);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }

                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isSuccsess = false;
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("la", "nie udało sie");
                isSuccsess = false;
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.shutdownInput();
                    socket.shutdownOutput();
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(isSuccsess){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Zdjęcie zostało wysłane !" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                bm = null;
                clearEt();
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Nie udało się wysłać zdjęcia !" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            pbWheel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pbWheel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post your question again. Better answer the questions at your first post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679274/java-android-socket-dont-disconnect

Comment: Have you checked the console? I mean, is there any exception?

Comment: @mallaudin there is no exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>`, and return any integer instead of a null in the doInBackground.

Just replace (in the doInBackground)

```
return null;
```

with

```
return 1;
```

and replace (in the AsyncTask declaration)

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
```

with

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
```

Comment: AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>  any type other than void is fine in the 3rd parameter

Comment: This is not true. `AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> ` will still call `onPostExecute`

Comment: I assumed using a void return type would not return any data from the doInBackground, and thus not invoke the onPostExecute. I am sure using an Integer instead works.

Comment: You are assuming it wrong. If it does not return any data, it doesn't mean we don't need `onPostExecute`. Better not to post assumptions.

Comment: I have removed that part from the answer

Answer (score 1):

Note that `getInputStream()` is a **blocking call**. It will block, until it receives data from server. In your case, you are **not** flushing data to server before calling `getInputStream()`, which will wait for response from server. Now you haven't sent any data to server (which I guess you should in your case to get response), socket will block the thread waiting for input.

You should **flush data before** getting input stream and making your thread sleep. Also close all streams once you are done, as closing stream will close underlying socket. From the docs:

> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.
>
> Closing the returned InputStream will close the associated socket.

```
outputStream.flush(); // flush it before sleep and don't close
// outputStream.close(); don't close it here
 try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you execution going after this lines?

```
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }
```

Use `URLConnection` instead of socket inside AsyncTask.